# What methods to call for handling events for UIObject?

Tags: ios, iphone

Is there a pattern Apple follows for which methods to call for handling an event for a UI objects?

What I mean is, to set an action for UIButton is `[button addTarget:action:forControlEvents]`
and for an ImageView I have to `[imageView addGestureRecognizer]`

I can never remember what methods to call. Is there an easy way to remember?

Comment: They are not set in stone, you can do pretty much anything you want that fits your needs, like making an imageview behave like a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "pattern" is that it is normal behavior for a button to respond to control events while it is not very common for an image view to respond to user interaction. Normally if you want to have a tappable image, you would use a UIButton and set an image on it. Apple decided to write the control events into UIButtons but not normal UIViews or UIImageViews.

So basically, you can use a control event if it is a button, otherwise you must use a different method. For normal views, gesture recognizers are a good option.